# Renaming UIDocument using UINavigationItemRenameDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uidocument

I'm trying to rename `UIDocument` open via document browser (`UIDocumentBrowserViewController`).

You can rename open documents in Apple Pages and Apple Numbers, and they use the usual `UINavigationItemRenameDelegate` controls.

Do these apps have special privileges for doing that? It appears that you can't use `NSFileCoordinator` or `NSFileManager` to achieve this, as the sandbox bookmark doesn't allow the file to be renamed or moved. The apps by Apple do this with no issue, though.

In my `Info.plist` I have:

```
UIFileSharingEnabled: true
LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace: true
```

And the following entitlements:

```
com.apple.security.read-write.user-selected: true
com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only: true
com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope: true
```

`UIDocument` documentation doesn't mention anything about sandboxing preventing renaming document files via `UINavigationItemRenameDelegate`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocument

All the information online seems antiquated, except for this manual page, which doesn't really clarify my issues. Are the proprietary Apple apps using private methods / special entitlements to do this, or am I missing something here?

**Update 2023-07-05**:

[WWDC session from 2022](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10069/?time=765) has the following code snippet, and according to the talk, you should use `UIDocumentWroserViewController` to rename files:

```swift
extension ViewController: UINavigationItemRenameDelegate {
    func navigationItem(_ navigationItem: UINavigationItem, didEndRenamingWith title: String) {
        // Try renaming our document, the completion handler will have the updated URL or return an error.
        documentBrowserViewController.renameDocument(at: <#T##URL#>, proposedName: title, completionHandler: <#T##(URL?, Error?) -> Void#>)
    }
}
```

This is even more confusing. Should I instantiate a new document browser view controller? When doing that, I get the following error:

```
ERROR! Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection from pid 3241 on anonymousListener or serviceListener was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection from pid 3241 on anonymousListener or serviceListener was invalidated from this process.}
[DocumentManager] The view service did terminate with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}
[DocumentManager] The UIDocumentBrowserViewController view service crashed for too many times in a row.
[DocumentManager] The view service did terminate with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tons of trial and error, the answer was somewhat simple:

- Set up your title bar to editor mode
- Make your view controller conform to `UINavigationItemRenameDelegate`
- Add a public variable for `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` and when instantiating your document view, hook it up:

```swift
let documentViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DocumentViewController") as! MyDocumentViewController
documentViewController.document = MyDocument(fileURL: documentURL)
documentViewController.documentBrowser = self
```

Now, in your `navigationItem:didEndRenamingWithTitle:` you can call the document browser to rename your file.

```objectivec
-(void)navigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)navigationItem didEndRenamingWithTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    [self.documentBrowser renameDocumentAtURL:self.document.fileURL proposedName:title completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable finalURL, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            self.titleBar.title = self.document.fileURL.lastPathComponent.stringByDeletingPathExtension;
            return;
        }
        
        [self.document presentedItemDidMoveToURL:finalURL];
    }];
}
```

Swift:

```swift
func navigationItem(_ navigationItem: UINavigationItem, didEndRenamingWith title: String) {
    self.documentBrowser.renameDocument(at: self.document.fileURL, to: title) { finalURL, error in
        if let error = error {
            self.titleBar.title = self.document.fileURL.lastPathComponent.deletingPathExtension
            return
        }
        
        self.document.presentedItemDidMove(to: finalURL)
    }
}
```

Apple should really include a minimal example in their documentation.